# Counting numbers of even numbers and odd numbers in java array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a program that reads a list of integers, and then display the number of even numbers and odd numbers. We assume that the input ends with 0. Here is the sample run of the program.

Input numbers: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0

Odd: 5    Even: 4

However, my result is 
Odd: 5 and Even: 5.

The problem is that 0 is counted as an even number. This is my code

```
public class Q75 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner (System.in);
        double [] numbers = new double[10];
        System.out.print("Enter numbers: ");
        for(int i = 0;i<numbers.length;i++){
            numbers[i] = input.nextDouble();
        }

        int Evens = 0;
        int Odd = 0;

        for(int i = 0;i<numbers.length;i++){
            if(numbers[i]%2 == 0){
                Evens++;
            }else{
                Odd++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The number of odd numbers: " + Odd);
        System.out.println("The number of even numbers: " + Evens);
    }

}
```

Comment: javascript =/= java

Comment: *How should I fix?* Fix what?

Comment: You never told us what the problem is, though I don't like using `Scanner#nextDouble()` and would rather use `Scanner#nextLine()`.

Comment: The question is not clear enough. Also, remove the tag `javascript` because it has nothing to do with java.

Comment: i assume that your problem is the input loop.
i would recommend that you add "if" that check if the number is 0

Comment: Put up a [mcve] please.

Comment: Aside: I think you prefer `int` or `long` for your numbers, not `double`. Java coding conventions say variables begin with a small letter, so use `evens` and `odd`.

Comment: I don't think the code is wrong. Zero is even! (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero). But if you want to say it isn't, you'll have to treat zero as special case since 0 mod 2 = 0.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options

A) Adding another branch in your if statements i.e.

```
if(number[i] > 0) {
   if(number[i] % 2 >0)
      Odd++;
   else 
      Evens++;
}
```

NB: changing the else branch to `else if(number[i] >0)`, you can do without the outer if condition.

B) Since the list of number ends with 0 you can put this as a condition in your for loop i.e.

```
for(int i =0; i < numbers.length && numbers[i] > 0 ; i++)
```

Also as a rule of thumb variable names in java start with a small letter

Answer (score 0):

Just don't check the last element: Use `i < numbers.length - 1`

```
for(int i = 0;i < numbers.length - 1; i++) {
        //
}
```

Comment: This requires you know the 0 is in the last element (and nowhere else). I recommend that you at least check the assumption.

Comment: Yes. the program said so. It will still consider any 0 that is in the middle of the array.